# Littlewood-Richardson coefficients for zonal polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions

The Littlewood-Richardson coefficients $c^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ appear in the expansion of a product of Schur functions into Schur functions, $s_{\mu}(x)s_\nu(x)=\sum_\lambda c^\lambda_{\mu\nu}s_\lambda(x)$. There is a combinatorial rule for computing these coefficients.

Zonal polynomials are somewhat similar to Schur functions (both are particular cases of Jack polynomials and are related to representation theory). Is there a combinatorial rule for computing the analogues of the LR coefficients for zonal polynomials?

There is already a similar question ([Littlewood-Richardson coefficients for Jack symmetric functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169046/littlewood-richardson-coefficients-for-jack-symmetric-functions)) for Jack polynomials, but I am interested in a specific and certainly simpler case.

Answer (score 3):

[It seems that this paper, Thm. 4.1](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81177364.pdf),
gives an expression for such coefficients, in terms of Zonal characters. This seem to be the closest so far.

Comment: Sadly, right after that theorem, the authors state that "To this date, there is no combinatorial rule, like the Littlewood-Richardson rule, for computing the coefficients $b^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$." But this paper is 27 years old, so one might hope for some development since then... maybe particular cases of $b^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ are known?

Comment: Name of this paper: [Bergeron and Garsia - Zonal polynomials and domino tableaux](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(92)90360-R).